# Google maps API javascript for Qualtrics, dark map

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

Like other questions I am getting the gray map with "for development purposes only" printed across. I have tried everything, billing is good, etc. When I do the chrome checker, this is what I get:

ERROR: This site doesn't seem to be using an API key. 
JS API Call #1:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places

This Call is repeated 4 times. Can anyone help me with this? I am new to javascript and so it's hard for me to understand anyway.

Comment: Make sure you are authenticated by using the correct token. 

Make sure you have a payment plan.

Make sure you did not have any HTTP filtering on the token.

If all else fails, my company just made the move to mapbox - it was a lot simpler to  use and for a third of the cost.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting "for development purposes only" it means your card info on your google account is wrong or you're using the wrong API key, my guess is that your API key is wrong, double check that!

Also, on top of being sure that you're using the right ones, Google provides you with a public key and a secret key if you're doing anything on the back end. Make sure to only use the public key on the front end or you may be charged for more than you'd expect if you publish your secret key, AFAIK.